# How to find index of int array which match specific value

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

I have

```
int myArray[]= {12,23,10,22,10};
```

So i want to get `index of 23` from  `myArray` with out iterating any loop (`for` ,`while` ...) .

I would do something like `Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf(23)`

This is not work for me . I get `-1` as output .

This is work with `String[]` 
Like

```
  String myArray[]= {"12","23","10","22","10"}; 
  Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf("23")
```

So why this is not working with `int[]` ? ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Integer myArray[]= {12,23,10,22,10};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf(23));
```

will solve the problem

`Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf(23)` this search about objects so we have to use object type of `int` since `int` is primitive type.

```
String myArray[]= {"12","23","10","22","10"}; 
Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf("23");
```

In second case this will work because `String` is object.

When we define a `List`,We define it as `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`. so primitives are not use in `List`. Then `Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf("23")` find index of equivalent Object.

Comment: '@Ruchira' i agree with this . So How can  we convert primitive type to object ?

Comment: @ankit337 you can use  Apache lang library(http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to do the following `Integer[] newArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(oldArray);`

Answer (score 4):

I concur with Ruchira, and also want to point out that the problem has to do with the fact that `int` is a primitive while `String` and `Integer` are actual objects.  (note I would have posted this as a comment but can't until 50 reputation ;) )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert an array of primitives to a list of boxed primitives, take advantage of [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) . Once you have the list, as shown below, use the API in List to find object by index.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(myArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider keeping your array sorted and use binary subdivision to decide an index. Insert and lookup would both be O(log(n)) in this case (instead of O(1) and O(n) respectively).

If you're doing a lot of looking up you might want to use a different data structure such as a hash map, not just for performance but also because it can be easier to write around.